# How can I put the /user.slice under the /system.slice?

Tags: linux, systemd, kubernetes

When running a Kubernetes cluster, it is [recommended that `/user.slice` resides under the `SystemReserved` top level cgroup](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/node-allocatable.md#general-guidelines) (i.e. under `/system.slice`).

According to the [systemd.slice documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html), a slice's name encodes its location in the hierachy, so how can I rename the existing `user.slice` unit to `system-user.slice` so that this is so, without renaming the existing system file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/user.slice` (as this is bad practice) and make sure that [systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html) uses `system-user.slice` for user login sessions instead.

Alternatively, if the slice unit renaming is not possible, is it possible to just configure systemd-logind to place user sessions under a slice other than `/user.slice`?

- `uname -a`: Linux ip-10-99-55-207.eu-west-1.compute.internal 4.16.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 12 09:08:05 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- `cat /etc/centos-release`: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Comment: That is an expression of desire for systemd to work differently in a proposal document, not a recommendation of good practice.

Comment: @JdeBP is this regarding renaming the system slice units? So are you saying renaming a system (slice) unit is okay?